# Injection with heritage and CDI

Tags: cdi

I have a question about heritage and CDI.
Given two interfaces:

- Car interface
- SportCar that extends Car

  ```
   interface Car {
   }

  interface SportCar extends Car{

  }


  class DefaultCar implements Car {

  }


  @FerrariQualifier
  class DefaultSportCar implements SportCar {

  }
  ```

**What I would like to inject:**

```
    @Inject
    private Car car; //inject DefaultCar

   @Inject 
   @FerrariQualifier
   private Car ferrari; //inject DefaultSportCar


  @Inject
  private SportCar sportCar;//inject DefaultSportCar
```

How can I do that?

Comment: it would be helpful to actually show the ambiguous resolution exception you get with the current code, assuming that's your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Without any further examples or explanation, you'd need to inject the first one with qualifier @Default.

This obviously requires any further 'Car' to have a non-@Default qualifier attached to it, otherwise you have an ambiguous resolution and you're trying to shoehorn something into CDI that doesn't fit.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood the CDI injection a bit. Especially that you want to do this:

```
@Inject
private Car car; //inject DefaultCar
```

Because **any** car implementation (sport car or ordinary one) will fit here and you will end up with ambiguous resolution.

As a temporary solution, you might make use of the `@Default` qualifier as noted by user *covener* but this is bound to break as soon as you introduce any other car implementation without qualifier.

The cleanest solution is perhaps re-thinking the design and altering the hierarchy like this:

```
interface Car {
  // all cars, place common methods here
 }

interface SportCar extends Car{
  // interface for all sport cars
}

interface ClassicCar extends Car{
  // interface for all non-sport cars
  // this is what you will inject
}

class DefaultCar implements ClassicCar {

}

@FerrariQualifier
class DefaultSportCar implements SportCar {

}
```

With this you can then:

```
@Inject
private ClassicCar car;
```

And get an instance of `DefaultCar`. Rest of your injections will work the same way.

The other solution is to use qualifiers.

Generally speaking - whenever you bump into ambiguous resolution, you have more than one bean eligible for injection and you need to narrow the selection by either using qualifiers or injecting a more specific interface/class.